# CLOBS over dblink - chunking function returning "buffer too small" error

Tags: oracle, clob, dblink

We have a chunking function we borrowed to bring back CLOBS over a DB Link in Oracle:

```
create or replace function fn_dblink_clob(
    p_dblink    in varchar2
  , v_remote_table in varchar2
  , p_clob_col  in varchar2
  , p_rid       in urowid
)
return clob is
    /**  A function to fetch a CLOB column over a dblink  **/
    /**  Laurence Prescott 25-Aug-17  **/
    /**  select dblink_clob('some_dblink', 'some_clob_column', rowid)
           from some_table@some_dblink;
         Note: Does not work on tables that have a virtual column (eg. xmltype).
    **/

    c_chunk_size    constant pls_integer := 4000;
    v_chunk         varchar2(5000);
    v_clob          clob;
    v_pos           pls_integer := 1;
begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_clob, true, dbms_lob.call);
    loop
        execute immediate 
            'select dbms_lob.substr@' ||p_dblink|| '(' ||p_clob_col|| ', ' ||c_chunk_size
         || ', ' ||v_pos|| ') from ' ||v_remote_table|| '@' ||p_dblink|| ' where rowid = :rid '
        into v_chunk using p_rid;
        begin dbms_lob.append(v_clob, v_chunk);
        exception when others then
            if sqlcode = -6502 then exit; else raise; end if;
        end;
        if length(v_chunk) < c_chunk_size then exit; end if;
        v_pos := v_pos + c_chunk_size;
    end loop;
    return v_clob;
end fn_dblink_clob;
```

It has worked well, but we are no seeing it throw this error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from SAPP_TRANSCT_DB
ORA-06512: at "PV_COMPLIANCE.FN_DBLINK_CLOB", line 22
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

CLOBS over DBLINKs are my arch nemesis.  I don't know which record is causing it, and dont want to iterate over 5 million records in a cursor to see where it breaks.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Try to set C_CHUNK_SIZE 4 times smaller (e.g. 1000) than C_CHUNK (e.g. 4000). Maybe it is about multi-byte characters that made substring too large.

Comment: Yep, unicode chars may be exceeding the 4K byte limit of the SQL varchar2 data type. Even though you are insertting into a varchar2(5000), that's a PL/SQL type into which the return value of the dbms_lob.substr is being placed at fetch... but dbms_lob.substr itself will build a SQL varchar2 type as its output, and that's limited to 4K bytes.

Comment: 1000 is the safest value.. the largest characterset is 4 bytes per character, so if 100% of the character use 4-bytes (like some Asian language maybe), 1000 chars could require 4000 bytes, and that's the SQL limit. Unfortunately there's no SUBSTRB function for dbms_lob.

Comment: Thanks both, 1000 seems to have solved it!!